# Numpy int Bit Length

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find the number of bits necessary to represent an unsigned numpy integer (or each element in an array of integers) in binary, in the same way the python's `int.bit_length()` does, but it seems that numpy has no equivalent function.

For example:

```py
>>> int(0b1000).bit_length()
4
>>> np.uint8(0b1000).bit_length()
AttributeError: 'numpy.uint8' object has no attribute 'bit_length'
```

Can anyone help me find the correct function? My current approach is to convert each array element to a python int to find the bit length, which seems like an awful option, for speed and clarity:

```py
np.vectorize(lambda np_int: int(np_int).bit_length())
```

Comment: From the [Python-Reference docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/ints/bit_length.html) it seems that `bit_length()` determines a unique value `k` such that `2**(k-1) <= abs(x) < 2**k`. You could implement your own function to apply this to a Numpy integer as opposed to your conversion. The documentation link also offers a simple way to calculate `k` but it has a limitation. Hope this helps!

Comment: What's the use of such a value?c or values for an array of numbers?  You can't change the dtype to match.

Comment: @hpaulj It's part of an algorithm classifying numbers by continuity of the bits, e.g. all the bits in 6 (`0b110`) are continuous, but 5 (`0b101`) is discontinuous because there's a 0 between 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the ceiling of the log2 of your array.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=30)
x
# returns:
array([92,  7, 53, 24, 85, 53, 78, 52, 99, 91, 79, 40, 82, 34, 18, 26, 20,
        7, 47, 38, 78, 50, 15, 12, 54,  3, 91, 82, 22, 90])

np.ceil(np.log2(x)).astype(int)
# returns:
array([7, 3, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 6, 7, 6,
       4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 7, 5, 7])
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! I was a little concerned about the speed impact of a log function, but it actually improves performance over my vectorized function attempt by about 16x!

Comment: The built-in functions will always outperform a vectorized function.

Comment: This method will not work for powers of two (Example: 16 -> 4). To fix that issue and the one mentioned by @Mikhail, use `np.ceil(np.log2(x+1))`.

Comment: This will only work for numbers up to 2^53 as its going to by default use the double precision data type with a 53 bit mantissa.  However it should be reliable for unsigned numbers in that range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
np.uint8(0b1000).nbytes*8
```

where the *8 at the end is simply the number of bits per byte

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a function of the number itself, not of the minimum bytes used to store the number. E.g. 2 (`0b10`) is a 2-bit number, even though it has to take at least a byte in memory (`0b00000010`)

Answer (score 0):

The classic bit-twiddling hack algorithm should be easily adaptable to numpy:

[https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog)

Here is the variant there for 32-bit unsigned integers:

```
def bit_length(v):
  r =     (v > 0xFFFF) << 4; v >>= r
  shift = (v > 0xFF  ) << 3; v >>= shift; r |= shift
  shift = (v > 0xF   ) << 2; v >>= shift; r |= shift
  shift = (v > 0x3   ) << 1; v >>= shift; r |= shift
  return r | (v >> 1)
```

Given vectorization, for very large lists and numbers up to the mantissa size 2^53 by default for doubles, it might be better performance to use the floating point log2 method.  It's not really slow.  Numpy needs to offer a CTZ or CLZ functions otherwise as counter-leading zeros or counter-trailing zeros is all that happens here.  Incidentally floating point log2 is not doing much more than these same CPU type operations.  So its probably not as inefficient as might seem.